# Monitor and manage spring cloud data flow (SCDF) Server using Prometheus

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, grafana, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to monitor and manage spring cloud data flow(SCDF) server itself using Prometheus?

I am aware that, I can monitor and collect metrics for the jars deployed in SCDF Server (i.e source, processors, sink).

But my question is, if I hit URL **http://localhost:9393/actuator/prometheus** will I get metrics related to SCDF server alone. I tried it, I did not get result.

I ran the SCDF jar.

> java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.11.1.jar

Comment: Is this it: https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/concepts/monitoring/?

Comment: @markalex, Yeah. But in which endPoint can prometheus collect metrics?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is, for spring cloud data flow server metrics are exposed in **/management/prometheus** endPoint and not in /actuator/prometheus endPoint.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I you look at the [docker-compose](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/main/src/docker-compose/docker-compose-prometheus.yml) file for using prometheus for local testing you will see the properties added to dataflow and skipper as well as the deployment of prometheus-proxy. You can also look at the Kubernetes deployment, in the same folder tree, for guidance.
You will most probably not spend time monitoring dataflow or skipper server themselves since they don't consume much resources and are only active when you interact with them directly. The [Task](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#tasks-monitoring) and [Stream](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#streams-monitoring) monitoring guides will provide more useful information regarding monitoring a solution.